# How to remove bounding box while saving a file?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a frame running with a small bounding box on the forehead. While if some certain condition is met the image must be saved. So when I use `cv2.imwrite(filename,frame)` , it saves the current frame but what I need is an image that doesn't contain a bounding box.

(i.e) My live webcam feed must have a small bounding box at my forehead but when I save that image I the bounding box must not be present in the final image that is saved into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep 2 copies of same frame, one with bounding box and one with clean image. when certain condition is met save the clean one. I think that it is much easier and cleaner solution than removing the bounding box.

Comment: Can you share some code and the error message you got so that I can take a look at.